# Преобразование времени в словесную форму

Tags: алгоритм, javascript

Кто знает, где взять javascript функцию, которая заданное количество секунд преобразует в формат:

> HH час(а/ов) MM минут(а/ы) SS секунд(а/ы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function timeRus(amount,timename){
    var problem_of_teen = amount%100;
    if(timename=='секунды'){
        var base='секунд';
        var endings = new Array('','','а','ы');
        }
    if(timename=='минуты'){
        var base='минут';
        var endings = new Array('','','а','ы');
        }
    if(timename=='часы'){
        var base='час';
        var endings = new Array('ов','ов','','а');
        }
    if(problem_of_teen >= 11 && problem_of_teen <= 19){
        return amount+" "+base+endings[0];
    }
    problem_of_numerals = amount%10;
    if(problem_of_numerals==0 || (problem_of_numerals>=5 && problem_of_numerals<=9)){
        return amount+" "+base+endings[1];
    } 
    if(problem_of_numerals==1){
        return amount+" "+base+endings[2];
    } 
    if(problem_of_numerals>=2 && problem_of_numerals<=4){
        return amount+" "+base+endings[3];
    } 
}
```

USAGE:

```
timeRus(12,'часы')+timeRus(48,'минуты')+timeRus(40,'секунды');
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!

Comment: доллары тока уберите: переделывал из PHPшной :)